# How do I display correlation coefficients of each individual variable in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I ran a linear regression model and have my coefficients. How do I print my variables next to my coefficients?

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=";")
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[["age", "area", "bedrooms"]],df.price)
print(reg.coef_)

Output 

[ 6.55199614e-02 -1.86317709e+00  2.20902007e-02]
```

I want the output to be

```
age coef: 6.55199614e-02
area coef: -1.86317709e+00
bedroom coef: 2.20902007e-02
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach is `pd.Series(reg.coef_,index=df.columns)`, then printing comes for free. Also it is easier to work with `pd.Series` for other calculations, comparisons of models via `pd.concat` etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print your variables next to your coefficients, you can use something like that:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=";")
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

colnames = ["age", "area", "bedrooms"]

reg.fit(df[colnames],df.price)

coefs_map = dict(zip(colnames, reg.coef_))

for k,v in coefs_map.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your solution. Please, where do you get your res?

```python
for k in coefs_map.keys():
    print(f"{k}: {res[k]}")
```

Comment: hey, sorry was probably some variable I forgot to add
I've updated the solution with using key and value pairs from `coefs_map.items()` (items in dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that
`'\n'.join(col+' coef: '+str(coef) for (col, coef) in zip(df.columns, reg.coef_))` gets you what you asked for. However, I recommend the following, as it gives output that is easier to read:

```
pad_length = 8+max(len(col) for col in df.columns)
output = '\n'.join((col+' coef: ').ljust(pad_length)+str(coef) for 
    (col, coef) in zip(df.columns, reg.coef_))
```

Also, all of this assumes that your column names are all already strings. If they're not, you should replace `col` with `str(col)`.